# document ready function stops redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The below form "View this product" when submitted will trigger this function which will get the product id[form_data] and will be passed as url parameter along with form data. I am successful till getting the form_data *but* page not getting redirected.

I strongly doubt my function not ended up properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
            $(".form-item").submit(function(e){
                var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
                window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(form_data);
                button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text

        });
});
```

Submit form:

```
<form class="form-item">
<input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
<button type="submit">view this product</button>
```

Comment: The page is not redirecting because `e.preventDefault();` is cancelling the `submit` event.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` This is stopping the redirection.

Comment: tried with not using preventdefault  as well still no progress.. edited the question removing e.preventdefault bcos that not causong problem

Comment: Why are you not using `GET` method in your form? Why are you manually encoding the form data and adding it to the url?

Comment: @prog you should probably just use the button click event of the `submit` button instead of the `submit` event. You'll use `e.preventDefault();` to cancel the submit event, however the button's events (like the redirect) should still fire.

Comment: bcos its takes dynamic data so thought this will suit for this problem

Comment: removing event.preventDefault was incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic data? In what way does `GET` not do the job?

Comment: And why would you do `?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(form_data)`, when `form_data` is already a valid and properly encoded param string? you should in that case remove `variable=` and not re-encode it.

Comment: @Santi yes couldnot figure out why so it happens though it seems right

Comment: @kevin without encoding its not getting redirects and sure that is not the issue for this case

Comment: You might need a full url here: `window.location = "1stlink.php...`

Comment: @Santi could you please provide me an example w.r.t my problem as you suggested ,as an answer, hope its close to my solution!

Answer (score 0):

Except for the "Adding..." dialog this can be done without any Javascript at all:

```html
<form method='GET' action='1stlink.php' class="form-item">
<input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
<button type="submit">view this product</button>
</form>
```